# Отправить письмо дальше в sendmail после заглушки

Tags: php, email, postfix

Здравствуйте.

Я пытаюсь сделать некоторую прослойку для писем на php 7.0, чтобы подвергнуть их небольшой обработке и самое главное - лимитированию исходящих писем.
В php.ini я перенаправил письма в свой файл, где открыл stdin поток и взял нужные данные, занес в таблицу, посчитал. Tеперь мне нужно отрпавить их обратно, причем тем же потоком отправить дальше в sendmail. Я очень долго гуглил это и до сих пор не нашел решения.

P.S. Все делаю я локально в докере, почтового сервера у меня нет, есть Postfix(по сути можно отправить в постфикс, но тут я даже близко понять не могу как), возможно, позже уже буду настраивать все это на сервере.

P.S.S Мне не нужны анологичные решения всей задачи, нужно сделать именно это.

Вот обрезанная часть кода, без логики и прочего, самое нужное для понимания вопроса.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$stream = '';
$fp = fopen('php://stdin','r');

while($t=fread($fp,2048))
{
    if( $t===chr(0) )
        break;
    $stream .= $t;
}
//$count_mails - количество писем с определенного домена. 
if($count_mails > 50){
    exit(0);
}
//вот здесь должно быть что-то что отправит письма дальше после всех изысканий.
```

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, решением стала строка:
    exec("echo '{$stream}' | sendmail -i -t");

Тоесть мы отправили дальше поток в sendmail, куда он собственно и шел.
Письма отловил я , чтобы протестить, с помощью фейкового почтового сервера, как только пришла идея его поставить, методом тыка и тестов решение нашлось быстро.

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно использую готовую библиотеку, поскольку функция mail() уже не актуальна, поскольку письма с левых серваков почтой гугл уже даже в спам не отправляются

```
// $mailSMTP = new SendMailSmtpClass('логин', 'пароль', 'хост', 'имя отправителя');
// $result =  $mailSMTP->send('Кому письмо', 'Тема письма', 'Текст письма', 'Заголовки письма');
```

а вот собственно библиотека

```
<?php
/**
* SendMailSmtpClass
* 
* Класс для отправки писем через SMTP с авторизацией
* Может работать через SSL протокол
* Тестировалось на почтовых серверах yandex.ru, mail.ru и gmail.com
* 
* @author Ipatov Evgeniy <admin@ipatov-soft.ru>
* @version 1.0
*/
class SendMailSmtpClass {

    /**
    * 
    * @var string $smtp_username - логин
    * @var string $smtp_password - пароль
    * @var string $smtp_host - хост
    * @var string $smtp_from - от кого
    * @var integer $smtp_port - порт
    * @var string $smtp_charset - кодировка
    *
    */   
    public $smtp_username;
    public $smtp_password;
    public $smtp_host;
    public $smtp_from;
    public $smtp_port;
    public $smtp_charset;

    public function __construct($smtp_username, $smtp_password, $smtp_host, $smtp_from, $smtp_port = 25, $smtp_charset = "utf-8") {
        $this->smtp_username = $smtp_username;
        $this->smtp_password = $smtp_password;
        $this->smtp_host = $smtp_host;
        $this->smtp_from = $smtp_from;
        $this->smtp_port = $smtp_port;
        $this->smtp_charset = $smtp_charset;
    }

    /**
    * Отправка письма
    * 
    * @param string $mailTo - получатель письма
    * @param string $subject - тема письма
    * @param string $message - тело письма
    * @param string $headers - заголовки письма
    *
    * @return bool|string В случаи отправки вернет true, иначе текст ошибки    *
    */
    function send($mailTo, $subject, $message, $headers) {
        $contentMail = "Date: " . date("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " UT\r\n";
        $contentMail .= 'Subject: =?' . $this->smtp_charset . '?B?'  . base64_encode($subject) . "=?=\r\n";
        $contentMail .= $headers . "\r\n";
        $contentMail .= $message . "\r\n";

        try {
            if(!$socket = @fsockopen($this->smtp_host, $this->smtp_port, $errorNumber, $errorDescription, 30)){
                throw new Exception($errorNumber.".".$errorDescription);
            }
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "220")){
                throw new Exception('Connection error');
            }

            $server_name ='test' /*$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]*/; 
            fputs($socket, "HELO $server_name\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "250")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Error of command sending: HELO');
            }

            fputs($socket, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "334")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Autorization error');
            }



            fputs($socket, base64_encode($this->smtp_username) . "\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "334")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Autorization error');
            }

            fputs($socket, base64_encode($this->smtp_password) . "\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "235")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Autorization error');
            }

            fputs($socket, "MAIL FROM: <".$this->smtp_username.">\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "250")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Error of command sending: MAIL FROM');
            }

            $mailTo = ltrim($mailTo, '<');
            $mailTo = rtrim($mailTo, '>');
            fputs($socket, "RCPT TO: <" . $mailTo . ">\r\n");     
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "250")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Error of command sending: RCPT TO');
            }

            fputs($socket, "DATA\r\n");     
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "354")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Error of command sending: DATA');
            }

            fputs($socket, $contentMail."\r\n.\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "250")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception("E-mail didn't sent");
            }

            fputs($socket, "QUIT\r\n");
            fclose($socket);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return  $e->getMessage();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private function _parseServer($socket, $response) {
        while (@substr($responseServer, 3, 1) != ' ') {
            if (!($responseServer = fgets($socket, 256))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (!(substr($responseServer, 0, 3) == $response)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```